# Is there theoretical limit on the minimal achivable focal length?

Tags: optics, lenses

There seems to be a limit, around 0.33, on the fastest possible aperture of a photographic lens made of glass. Is there a theoretical limit on the minimal focal length of a photographic lens (rectangular projection, not a fisheye)? Are the physical reasons that would prevent a, say, 1 mm focal length lens for a full frame sensor?

I also asked this question on [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106672/is-there-theoretical-limit-on-the-minimal-focal-length-for-a-given-sensor-size), but didn't get quite the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just some thoughts...From the Wikipedia article Lens, we have the Lensmaker's Equation for a single lens:

[image: Lensmaker's Equation]

where f is the focal length, n is the material index of refraction, d is the thickness and R1 and R2 are the radii of curvature. Let's for simplicity consider a plano-convex lens, with R2 infinite. The equation then reduces to f = R1/(n-1). So smaller and smaller f can be achieved with smaller and smaller radius of curvature, which implies smaller and smaller aperture since you can't have a big lens with a small radius. There doesn't appear to be any theoretical limit here.

Now if we are talking about a very short focal length photographic lens, it would have to be positioned very close to the sensor in order to achieve focus, which I would think would lead to handling and mounting issues.

Comment: That's great for a photographic lens consisting of one element, but most of them (all of them?) consist of multiple elements.

Comment: the more elements you add, the larger the resulting lens combination will be, however, the image must be outside of the lens for imaging purpose and therefore a larger lens forces a longer focal length.